# I`ve got some problems with new Acer Aspire S3

Tags: bluetooth, brightness, acer, intel, aspire

I just got a new Acer Aspire S3 Laptop, and I've installed Ubuntu on it. Here is some problems:

**1.** Bluetooth (AR3012) can't find any devices. rfkill shows that everything is fine, but I still can't connect to any device. (Maybe it was turned off in stock windows?)

**2.** Can't change screen brightness (I've tried Timex's solution with new 3.2-rc kernel and some grub options, touchpad works fine,but I still can`t use Fn+Right/Left)

**3.** 720p video in all players(VLC, mplayer and totem) works wrong. I found some similar problems on intel video chips with vblank sync or something like that. Video plays as it should, but i always see a line which appears on action scenes (looks like some parts of a screen updates faster)

Maybe there are some solutions from similar laptops that I can find?

PS I've tried ubuntu 11.04 with old kernel and linux mint 12-rc with 3.2-rc2 kernel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Bluetooth works with kernel patch
2) Brightness needs lines in /etc/default/grub

```
    pcie_aspm=force
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="quiet splash pcie_aspm=force i915.i915_enable_rc6=1 acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

3) This problem calls "Screen Tearing". New intel video drivers will probably fix this.

Very similar laptop is Asus Zenbook UX21/31... It uses similar wifi/bt module...

Comment: If this is the answer to your question you should [accept it](http://askubuntu.com/faq#howtoask) so others know it works. It also helps your reputation here.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to summarize the problems of the Acer Aspire S3 on Linux on this page.

http://www.linlap.com/wiki/acer+aspire+s3

Going on the 3.2 rc2 kernel way has proven wrong for me. Although the track-pad was recognized, I lost right click, and the possibility to click a zone selection. I went back to the stock Ubuntu kernel.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I`ve just found bluetooth solution. I`ve added my device id to btusb.c and ath3k.c and compiled kernel. Solution seems to be similar to Asus UX31.
I don`t know how to make and post patch.
$ diff btusb.c btusb.c.old
122,123d121
< { USB_DEVICE(0x13d3, 0x3375), .driver_info = BTUSB_ATH3012 },
< { USB_DEVICE(0x04ca, 0x3004), .driver_info = BTUSB_ATH3012 },
$ diff ath3k.c ath3k.c.old
73,74d72
< { USB_DEVICE(0x13d3, 0x3375) },
< { USB_DEVICE(0x04ca, 0x3004) },
91,92d88
< { USB_DEVICE(0x13d3, 0x3375), .driver_info = BTUSB_ATH3012 },
< { USB_DEVICE(0x04ca, 0x3004), .driver_info = BTUSB_ATH3012 },

Comment: @xcariba Can you give a more detailed explanation as to how you did this? I'm having the same issue with bluetooth and Kubuntu 13.04.